# Touch and Network+ app crashing in lumia 620

Tags: 8.1

My touch and network+ app is crashing in Lumia 620 after updating to WP 8.1.
Any suggestions how can it be fixed?

Comment: Is it updated to the last version? Did you try reinstall it?

Comment: Yes it is updated.. And I also tried reinstalling.

Comment: I asked because I have the same phone and when I updated to WP 8.1 (months ago) I remember one of the defaults App to crash on start. I also remember that lots of default Apps needed to be upgraded but the Store notified me of available upgrades only after some hours (and if I checked manually before, no update was showed).

Comment: Sir but my phone is updated to latest version and also the default apps but still I m facing this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the apps are all up to date your only option is to do a hard reset as you can't uninstall / reinstall those apps manually.
A hard reset usually fixes all issues caused by the WP8.1 update.

Comment: Okay sir. Thank you. I also think i m left with this as the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Go and download sysapp pusher and install the feature from there. That might fix it.

Comment: Already done..didn't worked